# pandas DataFrame - how to get the duration of different players

Tags: python, pandas, duration

I'm new to Python, and am analyzing bidding records using pandas. I'd like to know the duration (time of last bid-time of first bid) of each players (7000 people), but I have no idea how to proceed. See below the data:

```
name  bids  profit  date    WeekOfYear
JEFF    3   -75    2012-05-25   21
JEFF    13  -325   2012-05-25   21
eQB     1   -25    2012-05-25   21  
eQB     1   -25    2012-07-02   27
eQB     1   -25    2012-07-09   28
alianx  7   -175   2012-05-25   21
alianx  19  -475   2012-05-25   21
alianx  59  -1475  2012-05-26   21
alianx  13  -325   2012-05-26   21
alianx  7   -175   2012-05-27   21


Data columns (total 5 columns):
name_x        95640 non-null object
date          95640 non-null datetime64[ns]
```

Expected results:

```
name  duration first_time   last_time
JEFF     1     2012-05-25   2012-05-25
eQB      46    2012-05-25   2012-07-09
alianx   3     2012-05-25   2012-05-27
```

I'm having trouble calculating the first_time and last_time of each player, once tried:

```
data['last_time'] = data.groupby(['date','name_x']).max().reset_index()
```

But it seems not working.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your data based on what you proposed above (i.e. I didn't see `name_x` in the dataframe, but assume it must be there). I would try:

```
data['last_time'] = data.groupby(['name_x'])['date'].transform('max')
```